# Any way in Org to directly set a heading's state to a particular one?

Tags: org-mode, todo

The standard workflow for switching heading states in Org (`TODO`/`DONE`) is to leaf through them with `C-c C-t`, *or* to assign letters to them and switch directly to the wanted state. These seem to be exclusive, since they are invoked with the same hotkey. On top of that, if I add extra states, then either the sequence becomes rather long or I need to exclude some of them from the sequence and type them manually.

I'd like instead to have both the ‘standard’ sequence toggled with `C-c C-t`, and the option to switch to any particular state with a hotkey of my choosing (specifically, I'd likely make a menu of them and bind that somewhere under `SPC` in Doom). To this end, I'd need a function that switches to any state without going through the other ones—is there a standard function for this in Org? So far, I haven't seen one in the docs or third-party articles. Maybe Doom already has something like this, that I missed?

I *could* go through the code and try to kludge me up some custom function borrowing pieces from the original source—however Org's code is already rather hands-on and low-level, and I'd prefer to use whatever APIs it does provide, and stay away from the internals, lest I run into conflicts later after changes in Org.

Comment: Not quite sure what you need, you can swith any state with `(org-todo "WAITNING")`

Comment: See [Fast access to TODO states](https://orgmode.org/manual/Fast-access-to-TODO-states.html#Fast-access-to-TODO-states) in the manual.

Comment: @TianshuWang Seems to be exactly what I want. The function's name is not too intuitive—in the tradition of Elisp, frankly: I did look for something like `org-set-state` or anything related to states, but found nothing. However I probably *should* have found `org-todo` being called in the source. Anyway, if you add that as an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in comment, you can use `(org-todo "WAITING")` to switch to the specified state:

```
(org-todo &optional ARG)

When called through ELisp, arg is also interpreted in the following way:
none        -> empty state
""            -> switch to empty state
done        -> switch to DONE
nextset     -> switch to the next set of keywords
previousset -> switch to the previous set of keywords
"WAITING"     -> switch to the specified keyword, but only if it
                 really is a member of org-todo-keywords.
```